# PhoneGap - window.location not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying to load my web app in PhoneGap, but I can't seem to get it to redirect in iOS. It does redirect correctly in the browser, however. My JS, just to keep it simple, looks like this:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    console.log('Received Device Ready Event');
    window.location.href = "http://example.com";
},
```

My `config.xml` contains this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<allow-navigation href="*://example.com/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Any ideas why it would work in the browser, but not in iOS? I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. I was using the PhoneGap Developer app on iOS, and as it turns out, the CSP gets overwritten by that app. If you are wanting to test external links, you apparently need to compile the app and install it on the device instead of using the PhoneGap Developer app. See here: https://github.com/phonegap/connect-phonegap/issues/163